# Is there any analogue of flexbox in Qt?

Tags: c++, css, qt, flexbox

I create widget with answers which can be chosen by user and I want to place them like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yxs1bmq6/1/

Change the window size and look at the boxes.

Is there any simple way to do layout working like this?

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  box1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  box2
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-around;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 500px;
}
.box {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: When you say "Qt" do you mean widgets or QML?

Comment: @MrEricSir, I mean widgets, because I haven't tried QML much, but if there is analogue of flexbox in QML, I would consider using QML :)

Comment: Using QML, you can try to use [`Flow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html).

Comment: Using QtWidgets, you can follow [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) on how to generate a custom `QLayout`.

Comment: @m7913d, Thanks, it's what I need. You could post it as answer.
It remains to understand how to make alignment in the center.

Comment: You may try it out yourself and post it as an answer. I don't have the time to do it for now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. I wrote a set of bindings to the [Yoga](https://github.com/facebook/yoga) layout engine. Using flexboxes is much easier than standard Qt Quick layout tools. Published a source code [here](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qml-flexbox).

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 675
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "cyan"
        Flex {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width

            flexDirection: "row"
            flexWrap: "wrap"
            justifyContent: "spaceAround"
            alignItems: "center"
            alignSelf: "center"
            alignContent: "stretch"

            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is possble to do something with QML's grids and their `flow` properties.